Evaporator coils in attic air handler froze in summer
This happened for a second time. A pro came after the first round but nothing was found (he said refrigerant level is ok, did not find blocked pipes) . I saw ice over the coils during the second round. Also there is moisture visible on registers.
My suspicion is with the thermostat (or at least this appears to be the cheapest first act). It is a 20 year old Honeywell TH5220D.
Is there an easy way to test it?

Your suspicion is unlikely to be correct, as the thermostat does not affect the temperature of the coils. It merely signals the AC to run, or not to run. Insufficient airflow and low refrigerant do affect the temperature of the coils, as already answered in your prior question.

Check for dirt on the evaporator fins and for a blocked drain.

that is a old coil, clean it with spray cleaner made for that purpose
